# coredata icloudkit in swift with two database containers and three databases in one app

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit

I have a complicated core data icloudkit requirement for my app

The app requires two cloud containers

1st one (iCloud.com.mycompany.students) will be shared with my other apps.  The database can be a private database. which I plan to use core data + icloudkit (NSPersistentCloudKitContainer)

2nd icloud container (iCloud.com.mycompany.content) which will be only used by one app, it has two databases (the public and the private database share the same schema)
public database includes the built in content I plan to use regular icloudkit to access the data
private database includes the user created content which I plan to use NSPersistentCloudkitCountainer)

So do I need three database containers with two different icloud container identifiers ?

Do I need to create two models one to manage the students and another one is to manage user created content?

How can I creat the store description for coredata icloudkit to access the different database containers?

I am new to swift and cloudkit and core data.

Thanks